# Does $y[n] = x[n] \star (u[n]-u[n-2])$ have memory or is it memoryless?

Tags: discrete-signals, system-identification

$y[n] = x[n] \star (u[n]-u[n-2])$, by its definition is has to be a system with memory since it is depended from a fraction of time in the past, but if we calculate the difference $u[n]-u[n-2]$, it results $u[n]$ for $0 \le n < 2$, which is memoryless. And that sign $\star$ is convolution.

Comment: Absolutely right, I already updated my post

Comment: Your question is clearer now. So your system has an impulse response that is given by $h[n]=u[n]-u[n-2]$, where $u[n]$ is the unit step sequence, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: me, the Notation Nazi, didn't even notice that, Fat. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: but i did notice a small mistake with an inequality that i fixed.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yes, so basic that is so easily unnoticed... and thank you for correcting it instead of me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system $$y[n] = x[n] \star (u[n]-u[n-2])$$ where $u[n]$ is the unit step function, has memory.

Indeed the system is equivalent to $$y[n] = x[n] \star ( \delta[n] + \delta[n-1] ) \implies y[n] = x[n] + x[n-1]$$ and as it's clear from the given I/O relationship, the current value of the output $y[n]$, depends on the values input $x[n]$ at other times namely $x[n-1]$ (one step past value); hence the system has memory.